# How to detect that my app has crahed because it ran out of memory?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

Is there a way to find out (write to log) that my app hasn't just crashed, but has run out of memory? Can I install some kind of a global exception handler?
I have my own custom `Application` class, if that helps.

Note: the app has a native (C++) core, and I need to be able to detect that the core has run out of memory, as well as the Java wrapper. I don't need to know where it happened, though (don't think it's possible?..), just the fact.

Comment: do you get a tracelog when it crashes? when my apps run out of memory in the logcat it says outOfMemory exception

Comment: Have you tried `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)`?

Comment: @Squonk - Native allocation issues won't propagate through to java Exceptions.  In actuality, native allocations are entirely separate from Java ones as well, excepting only cases where jni code needs to allocate objects in the VM.

Comment: @TomerShemesh: I wouldn't know, it's on the client side and reading logcat requires a special permission which earned me a couple negative ratings, so I had to forget the idea of reading logcat output. If I could read it, debugging would become MUCH easier.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : There was no mention of using native code when I first read the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your crash log system like Acra, Crashlytics, Parse and so on. If you have time you should write your own, but that is not as simple as you may think. Too us a while to make a rock solid solution :/